# How to "ignore" files in the remote repo so that they are not included when updating a local copy?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitignore

I have a GitLab project with some files that I'd like to have only "remote" and not locally. Is this possible and how can I do this?

I tried using the .gitignore file but that didn't work (I guess the remote copy is treated differently than the local copy?)

Update: If not possible within the git system what would you recommend that I do? (I'm using GitLab)

Comment: No, Git's ignore system only prevent files from being tracked. It has no impact on tracked files.

Comment: @Chris Okay thanks, good to know, i've updated the question to expand it